# Why do they use 'winning by anywhere'?

Tags: grammar

Why do they use 'winning by anywhere' not 'winning everywhere' what is more clear for non native speaker?

> Exit polls have Jim Matthews **winning by anywhere**... from a nine to 12
>   percent margin of victory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the sentence incorrectly.

It is not:

> (**winning by anywhere**) (from X to Y)

But:

> (**winning**) (by anywhere from X to Y)

In other words:

> Exit polls have Jim Matthews ***winning*** *[and the votes for him exceed those for  the others]* by anywhere from a nine to 12 percent margin of victory.

---

Further, *anywhere from* is not being used to describe a place but a number range.

These two expressions are functionally equivalent:

> anywhere from a nine to 12 percent margin
>   a nine to 12 percent margin

The use of *anywhere from* only serves to provide emphasis.

---

Taking both into account, you could shorten the entire sentence into something like this:

> Exit polls have Jim Matthews winning by a 9–12 percent margin.

Answer (score 0):

The expression 'anywhere from [some quantity or number] to [some other quantity or number]' means 'an unspecified, unknown, or unstated quantity between a lower limit and an upper limit'. Since each such quantity is a single one, 'anywhere' is used, and not 'everywhere'. Repairing your TV could cost anywhere between $50 and $200, depending on what went wrong.